# Angular : Sort a nested list in an object in array

Tags: angular, typescript

Please can anyone help with a method in typescript that sorts an object nested in array by a property,
This photo is showing my whole object, and the nested object that I want to sort which is `details` by `priorityInDisplay`

[image: Screenshot of the object]

here is the object :

```
{
  Groupe : 1,
  GroupePrestation: "xxx",
  total: 200,
  details: {
    designation: "XXX",
    priorityInDisplay: "A"
  }
}
```

Comment: By what property do you want to sort it?
Can you paste your object please too!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to sort it By "priorityInDisplay" , I didn't past the object from the browser console, cuz it didn't look clear, so i just took an image which is clearer. the object has
 ***{ Groupe : 1, GroupePrestation:"xxx",total:200,details : { designation:"XXX",priorityInDisplay:"A"}}*** 
I want to sort the details object which is inside the whole object. thanks

Comment: Link to image is broken!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sort:

```js
groupes.forEach((groupe) => {
  groupe.details.sort((a, b) =>
    a.priorityInDisplay.localeCompare(b.priorityInDisplay)
  );
});
```

```js
var groupes = [
    {
        Groupe: 1,
        GroupePrestation: "xxx",
        total: 200,
        details: [
            {
                designation: "XXX",
                priorityInDisplay: "B",
            },
            {
                designation: "YYY",
                priorityInDisplay: "A",
            },
            {
                designation: "ZZZ",
                priorityInDisplay: "C",
            },
        ],
    },
];
groupes.forEach(function (groupe) {
    groupe.details.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.priorityInDisplay.localeCompare(b.priorityInDisplay);
    });
});
console.log(groupes);
```